# PHP object - Alternative way of use

Tags: php

I want to use a class method in multiple files.
Instead of declaring an object in each file, is it possible to create the object in a function and use this function where I need it?

Example:

```
class Test_Class {

    public function test_method() {
        // something
    }

}

function Test_Class_Init(){
    $test_class = new Test_Class();
    return $test_class;
}
```

Then call the method in this way in each file:

```
Test_Class_Init()->test_method();
```

Comment: Is `Test_Class_Init()` really saving you anything over just running `new Test_Class`? Or are you asking about how to share a single *instance* of the object (i.e. a singleton)?

Comment: well yes, but it's really just a level of indirection. You still have to write a line of code everywhere you need it. It's just a different line of code. Not really clear how this helps you, unless in reality initialising the class requires some more complex setup with multiple lines of code to set properties etc

Comment: If, as iainn mentions, you really want one instance (i.e. one copy) of the class to be shared everywhere, then google the Singleton Pattern

Comment: You may also use a static method.

Comment: No I don't need a single instance, this is just an idea for not declare over and over again the same object in a lot of file

Comment: But you still have to declare the thing that wraps around it many times over...so what's the difference? Like I said unless it means less lines of repeated code in your other files there's no advantage. If you just replace one line of code with a different line of code then it's a bit pointless. Just like any function really. Plus, global functions and global objects are generally an anti-pattern in an object-oriented application

Answer (score 1):

If your method is not reliant on any other data in the class, you could consider declaring it as [`static`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)...

```
class Test_Class {
    public static function test_method() {
        echo "Hello";
    }
}
```

you can then call it just referencing the class...

```
Test_Class::test_method();
```